# Laravel 5.2 How to get values from two or more table from a relationship

Tags: many-to-many, laravel-5

I have a default authentication table user and another table user_profiles

```
 user(id,email,password) 
 user_profiles(id,first_name,last_name,mobile)
```

i am connecting these two table using a many-to-many relationship
for this, i added relationship in the both model class- User and UserProfile

```
   // User Model
 public function userProfiles()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\UserProfile',  'user_user_profile', 
  'user_profile_id', 'user_id');
    }

 //UserProfile Model

 public function users()
    {
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_user_profile', 
  'user_profile_id', 'user_id');
  }
```

and i tried to access the UserProfle details via user table using

```
    $user=\App\User::find(1)->userProfiles()->get();
```

but not working and also tried

```
     /$user = \App\User::findOrFail(1)->with('userProfiles')->get();
```

that is also not working , please help to

1. Get the user_profile table details along with user table
2. How to access the Pivot table(user_id,user_profile_id) value
3. How to display these data from multiple tables into a view form?

Comment: what does not working means ? Are you getting any error ?

Comment: @jaysingkar no, there is no error . when i debug the output  iam getting null array

Comment: @jaysingkar when i try \App\User::find(1)->userProfiles()->get();
i am getting null array [2016-08-19 13:53:55] local.DEBUG: [ ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined the relationship wrong in your User Model: swap `user_id` and `user_profile_id`

```
// User Model
 public function userProfiles()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\UserProfile',  'user_user_profile', 
   'user_id' , 'user_profile_id');
    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot . worked perfectly.. 
i have another doubut, is there any way to get these two tables data within a single query,i am from  a cakephp background, in cake that is possible.

Comment: I think you can use `with()` method for that